# Extjs3.4 Validation on Input Value

Tags: validation, extjs

Below is extjs3.4 to display dialog screen.

I failed to get the input value for validation.

Anyone can help to take a look where should i capture the input value and implement the validation before submit to the system? Thanks a lot.

```
RemarkDialog = Ext.extend(Ext.Window,{
    modal:true,
    resizable:true,
    layout:"form",
    width:400,
    title:"Enter Comment",
    initComponent:function(){
        this.items = [{
            xtype: 'form',
            ref: 'formPanel',
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [{
                autoscroll:true,
                hideLabel: true,
                name: 'Remarks',
                itemId: "Remarks",
                xtype: 'textarea',
                maxlength : 55, 
                allowBlank: false
            }]
        }];

        this.bbar = [
            '->',
            {
                itemId:'submit',
                text:'Submit',
                handler:function(btn,e){
                    this.fireEvent('submitpressed', this.formPanel.getForm().getFieldValues());
                    this.destroy();
                },
                scope:this
            },{
                itemId:'cancel',
                text:'Cancel',
                handler:function(btn,e){
                    this.destroy();
                },
                scope:this
            }
        ];

        RemarkDialog.superclass.initComponent.call(this,arguments);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ext.form.BasicForm](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.BasicForm) has an `isValid` function that will return a boolean, and each field has a `validator` [config parameter](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.TextArea-cfg-validator) where you can supply your own validation function. For example, the field config could look like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'textarea',
    validator: function(value) {
        return /.+pink.+/.test(value);
    }
}
```

And your form submit handler could be set up like this:

```
handler:function(btn,e){
    if(this.formPanel.getForm().isValid()) {
        this.fireEvent('submitpressed', this.formPanel.getForm().getFieldValues());
        this.destroy();
    }
    else {
        alert('your textarea needs more pink');
    }
},
```